# Difference between module.exports in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the difference between

```
module.exports = UpgradeService;
```

and

```
module.exports = { UpgradeService };
```

When I used the second one, I wasn't able to peek its definition in VS code. Why this is happening and what are the similarities and differences between them?

Comment: One is creating an object literal with a single property, the other is not.

Comment: `{ UpgradeService }` is shorthand for `{ UpgradeService: UpgradeService }`.

Answer (score 3):

The first statement sets the exported value to `UpgradeService`. The second statement sets the exported value to an object. The `{ UpgradeService }` is a shorthand for `{ UpgradeService: UpgradeService }` which is a simple key:value pair! In other words, it exports a plain object that has only one (own) key: `UpgradeService`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that setting `module.exports = (something)` really is just changing what you get when you `require()` the module, and that `(something)` can be any value. You could set `module.exports = 42` and `require()` would return the number 42 just fine.

Doing `module.exports = { UpgradeService }` means that you're setting the export to an *object*, which looks like `{"UpgradeService": UpgradeService}`. That follows [the ES6 syntax rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) where `{x, y}` is the same as `{x: x, y: y}`.

Then in your other files, instead of doing `const UpgradeService = require('blah')`, you do `const UpradeService = require('blah').UpradeService`, or `const { UpgradeService } = require('blah')` with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Usually you set module.exports to an object (instead of a function or class) when you plan on exporting multiple things. For example, you might want to export both `UpgradeService` and, later, a new `Upgrade` class; in that case, you would do `module.exports = { UpgradeService, Upgrade }`.

Some people prefer to *always* start with exporting an object like that, because then it's easy to add a new exported thing. For instance, if you change `module.exports = 'Apple'` to `module.exports = { fruit: 'Apple', animal: 'Bat' }`, you have to change *all* files which required that module. But if you had just started with `module.exports = { fruit: 'Apple' }`, you would be able to add `animal: 'Bat'` without having to change any existing files.